# How to correctly apply the Fama&French with momentum to estimate the degree of outperformance?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, factor-analysis

I have a question about the use of the Fama & French factors.

I’m currently examining possible differences in abnormal earnings between to different type of real estate portfolios. To counter Roll’s (1977) critique on the use of Beta to estimate a portfolio’s degree of outperformance, I will include a few approaches.

Two different portfolio constructions are used:

1. the value;
2. and equally weighted

Four different market proxies are used:

1. CRSP value weighted index,
2. CRSP / Ziman Equity value weighted index,
3. a small cap index,
4. and S&P 500 index.

My first question is:
**Is it possible to use the (value weighted) FF factors with momentum to estimate the outperformance of the two different portfolios, since one is equally weighted while the other is value weighted?**

Another thing is the four different benchmarks. The first three returns are based on the NYSE, AMEX, and NASDAQ stocks, same as the four factors downloaded from Kenneth K French data library. However this will not be the case for the S&P 500 benchmark.

So, my second question is:
**Is it still useful to use these four factors or do I need to manually calculate them with data from the S&P 500 stock?**